# JAVA - readfile and put it on arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, readfile

i am doing a self project to help me understand more about java.but i am stuck at this question.
I have a following txt file :

```
Name  Hobby 
Susy  eat fish 
Anna  gardening
Billy bowling with friends
```

What is the best way to read all the line and put it in arraylist(name,hobby). but the tricky part is the

> eat fish or bowling with friends

has white spaces and it must be put under one array and obviously i cannot hardcode it. 
here is my current code

```
public void openFile(){
    try{
        x = new Scanner(new File("D://practice.txt"));
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("File could not be found");
    }
}

public void readFile(){
    while (x.hasNextLine()){
        x.nextLine();
        if (x.hasNext()){
            listL.add(x.next());
        } else {
            listL.add("");
        }

        if (x.hasNext()){
            listR.add(x.next());
        } else {
            listR.add("");
        }
    }
}
```

thanks in advance...
note = 1.hobby and name are separated by spaces
       2.names will only have one word only

Comment: Does the first word ever have a whitespace? Are names/hobbies separated by spaces or by tags? Give us more information, please.

Comment: If you mean make it go from `Billy bowling from friends` and add `bowling with friends` as an entry into your ArrayList, you could read the whole line, then split it at the first space character which comes between the name and the task in your text file. This can be accomplished with a substring function and indexOf. But if the name has more than one word, try changing the text file to use something like commas to separate names and tasks.

Comment: @Darkhogg 1.hobby and name are separated by spaces 2.names will only have one word only.

Comment: See the answer by @netinept, it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing `scanner.next()`, you may want to do something like this:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("D://practice.txt"));
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> hobbies = new ArrayList<String>();

while(scan.hasNext()){
    String curLine = scan.nextLine();
    int indexOfHobby = curLine.indexOf(' ');
    names.add(curLine.substring(0, indexOfHobby).trim());
    hobbies.add(curLine.substring(indexOfHobby).trim());
}
```

One problem with this is that there is no relationship between the two `ArrayList`s, so you have to be sure to mind your indices as you iterate through. One way to fix this would be to add a `Person` class so that you can have `name` and `hobby` as attributes of `Person`, then have an `ArrayList` of `Person`s. That might look like this:

```
Class Person {
    String name;
    String hobby;

    public Person(String name, String hobby){
        this.name = name;
        this.hobby= hobby;
    }
    // more methods here
}
```

Then, in your main class, you'd do this:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("D://practice.txt"));
ArrayList<Person> people= new ArrayList<Person>();

while(scan.hasNext()){
    String curLine = scan.nextLine();
    int indexOfHobby = curLine.indexOf(' ');
    people.add(new Person(curLine.substring(0, indexOfHobby).trim(), curLine.substring(indexOfHobby).trim() ));
}
```

Comment: Consider using `trim()` to remove whitespace surrounding names/hobbies

Comment: thanks @netinept. i will use your answer as my guidance in learning JAVA

Answer (score 0):

Also consider using a `Map<String,String>` to store people with their hobby together instead of keeping two different structures:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("D://practice.txt"));
Map<String,String> namesAndHobbies = new HashMap<String,String>();

while(scan.hasNext()){
    String line = scan.nextLine();
    int idx = line.indexOf(' ');
    String name = line.substring(0, idx).trim();
    String hobby = line.substring(idx).trim();

    namesAndHobbies.put(name, hobby);
}
```

This will allow you to access people by name, so you can find out the hobby of a person by name.
Use `namesAndHobbies.keySet()` to get a collection of all names and `namesAndHobbies.values()` to get a collection of all hobbies.